# SSL Certificate in Kafka Consumer in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am making consumer in `Asp.Net` using Confluent Kafka. Confluent kafka downloaded from Nuget package.

I want to connect with remote server where kafka is deployed using SSL certificate.

I am using config for connection:

```
var configSSL = new ConsumerConfig {
 GroupId = groupID,
  BootstrapServers = serverUrl,
  SslCaLocation = "Config/testcert.p12",
  SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Ssl,
  AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
  Debug = "all",
};
```

I am not able to connect kafka server using SSL certificate and I am getting error:

Error occurred: ssl.ca.location failed: No error

Answer (score 1):

You should try to follow the example in [here](https://github.com/mhowlett/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/security/examples/Security) to configure SSL correctly. It is written by the main *confluent-kafka-dotnet* contributor. But just by looking at your configuration I'd say you should try to use the full path for `SslCaLocation`.

Comment: Even  i used full path , i am getting same error:
var config = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{ 
    { "bootstrap.servers", "{server_hostname}:9093" },
    { "security.protocol", "SSL" },
    { "ssl.ca.location", @"C:\path\to\caroot\file\ca-root.crt" }
}

Error:

Error occurred: ssl.ca.location failed: No error

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a ca certificate and your certificates private key to connect with ssl to Apache Kafka in .NET.

```
var mutualAuthConfig = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{ 
    { "BootstrapServers", "{server_hostname}:9093" },
    { "SecurityProtocol", "SSL" },
    { "SslCaLocation", "your_ca_cert_path" },
    { "SslCertificateLocation", "your_cert_path" },
    { "SslKeyLocation", "your_key_file" },
};
```

The reason is that you issue your certificates via OpenSSL. For example, OpenSSL generates a file with the extension .pem and represents only a certificate. In the Java world, you can use a Java keystore that gives you a certificate that consists of a certificate and a private key.

You can view configuration examples here: https://github.com/mhowlett/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/security/examples/Security

This configuration should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Just double-click the `testcert.p12` file to install it on your machine. You needn't set up `SslCaLocation`.